# Is it possible to add (x,y) co-ordinates to menus in GLUT?

Tags: opengl, glut

I want different menus to be displayed when different screen locations are pressed. Is it possible to add (x,y) co-ordinates to menus in GLUT?

Answer (score 1):

No.

GLUT in general is very limited, and not really suitable for any advanced applications.

You can look into more full-featured OpenGL UI toolkits.